# Using custom icons as buttons in Bootstrap 4 navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to place a number of custom icon buttons on a Bootstrap 4 navbar. I have tried placing the buttons with something like this:

```
<a class="nav-item" href="#">
    <img class="png-icon d-inline-block align-middle" src="assets/png-icons/zoom full.png">
</a>
```

The button shows up on the navbar, but it is aligned at the top. I would like to have it middle aligned (vertical). I have tried all kinds of CSS styles like margin-top and padding-top but it does not change anything. I also tried to us class="d-inline-block align-middle", but the icon is still aligned at the top.

[Screenshot of miss aligned icon. I scaled it to be small to better illustrate the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AK54.png)

Can somebody help me with the correct way to use icons in Bootstrap 4 navbars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short-hack try following css:

```css
.align-middle {
    position:relative;
    top:4px
}
```

otherwise you can set padding instead of line-height, or remove floating from the image and place it as inline-element...

but: i would recommend icon-font-tools like icomoon for placing custom icons in your navbar. (http://icomoon.io/app/)

Comment: Thanks! That works. What is the advantage of using http://icomoon.io/app/ for placing icons?

Comment: if you use iconfonts, you can handle it like text (css color, font-size, text-align, hover-effects, and so on) .. furthermore its just one request, instead of multi-http-requests, if you need lots of icons... your site will load faster and you've got more options than using png's... and because its vector-format, it will look cleaner in each device (no blurry edges)

you see... there is not a single reason, still using png's for icons :)

Comment: But what if I need icons with a few colors e.g a document icon drawn with white lines with a red cross over it. Can that be done with icon fonts?

Comment: @Gøngevangen - sorry, a little delayed... not with iconfonts, but with svg-icons (also supported by icomoon)